# .rotate() callback function not working if i remove animateTo parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/YKj5D/2644/) where the callback function is getting called

```
$("#img").rotate({bind:{
      click: function(){
          $(this).rotate({
            angle: 0, 
            animateTo:10,
              duration:200,
            callback: function(){   
                $(this).rotate({
            angle: 340,
            animateTo:100,
              duration:400,
            callback: function(){   
                alert("success")
            }
          })

            }
          })
      }
  }
});
```

Now in the above code i am just removing the animateTo parameter and the call back is not working !!
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/YKj5D/2645/)

Why is this happening?! is the number of parameters play  a role in callback function !?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is Parameters

if youcheck this
[<kbd>Check here</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/AVafoQoq/1/)

then you can see that **onclick** nothing happening to logo

I have removed ***animate*** parameter also **onclick** event

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I done some more testing, and oufcourse you need all parameters in this case. Can't you just set the animateTo so it does nothing?

Comment: but how it works without ";" when i have animateTo parameter :O